# Is there a size/complexity limit to DataView.Sort?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dataview, limits

I may need to write a very complex equation for the `DataView.Sort` property (.NET Framework 4). Is there any known limit on string length or function nesting complexity?  My string may be ~500 chars in length with multiple depth levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dug up the .NET source code, and `Sort` literally only allows column names, brackets (`[]`) and `ASC`/`DESC`. So I guess the answer is Yes, there are quite strict limits on what is allowed.